# How to get an image from a file, and overwrite it in the same program?

Tags: c#, image, io

(Link to code: http://pastebin.com/0CHKnm6W)

My problem is as follows:

The program contains a function to import an image (this is under part 2). The path to the image is then saved in a class which contains the image.

The program contains a second function which takes the image as you edited it using the program, and then saves it to the original path (this being the original path matters quite a bit)

This gives an exception (IOException) because the path we want to save to contains an image that we are using. How can I fix this?

Comment: Options: Delete file, overwrite file, save as different name, save in different directory.

Comment: Please don't link to your code, add the relevant bits here directly in your post.

Comment: @tnw I think I did, the original code is thousands of lines, so this was pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Image.FromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx)

> The file remains locked until the Image is disposed.

You could could do it this way

```
using(var image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog.FileName))
{
    ...
    s.schetscontrol.MaakBitmapGraphics().DrawImageUnscaled(image, 0, 0);
    ...
}
```

Maybe [cloning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.clone.aspx) will works too.

Please consider next time provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) right here, hosting it elsewhere and in some strange language is not helpful at all when you need help. If you would spend 5 min formatting your sample, you'd get answer 1 hour earlier ;)